# MS Access SQL update query based on another query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

My DB has existing data.  I'm trying to implement some sort of security rights system.  It doesn't need to be truly secure...just limit what each level can effectively change.  Technically...one exists...but it needs to be beefed up.

I need to adjust the existing Rights level for people that are Instructors.  I have a query (qInstructors) that lists a DISTINCT query of anyone in the class table listed as an Instructor.  There are a total of 38 Instructors.

Now I need to update the User table to adjust the rights of those 38 people...and this is where I'm stuck.  A simple update query, no problem.  But I must not be searching with the correct term because I can't find anything to help me hammer out the SQL.

```
UPDATE tblUserList 
INNER JOIN tblUserList ON tblUserList.NTID = qInstructors.Instructor 
SET tblUserList.Rights = 2
WHERE [NTID]=[Instructor];
```

When I try to run this, I get a syntax error in the JOIN.  This is beyond my SQL knowledge...any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing this using `IN`:

```
UPDATE tblUserList 
    SET tblUserList.Rights = 2
    WHERE [NTID] IN (SELECT [Instructor] FROM qInstructors);
```

The use of `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` clause varies by database.  The `IN` version is ANSI standard and should work both in MS Access and in whatever back-end database you might be using.

Answer (score 1):

You were specifying the `tblUserlist` instead of `qinstructors` in the `join` clause.

```
UPDATE tblUserList 
INNER JOIN qInstructors ON tblUserList.NTID = qInstructors.Instructor 
SET tblUserList.Rights = 2
```

Comment: This did resolve the error, and I can view the resulting rows that match....however I'm apparently using an un-updatedable query and cannot actually update.

Answer (score 0):

Create a query in Design View.  Change the type to "Update Query".

Add your target table to the query, and add your existing "Give me instructors" query as well.

Drag a line from the ID in your target table to the corresponding ID returned by your Query.

Drag the field you want to update down to the grid at the bottom.  In the "Update To" field, enter "Allowed" or "True" or whatever indicates that something is allowed for instructors.